# How to implement zoom CSS property as a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement a function for the `zoom` css property in JavaScript; like how it is implemented in Chrome on Mac OS or Windows. This is because this is a non-standard property and its implementation can vary across browsers (Mozilla Firefox does not support it). I do not want to use the `transform: scale()` property because it does not change the actual size of the element within the DOM (unlike like `zoom`).

I am not sure how I would go on about doing this. For my case, I have an input with placeholder text and background image which I want to zoom to 1.1.

The code below is just a way to show the difference in zoom and scale for my case:

```js
const searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar-1")

const zoom = (element, value) => {
  
}

zoom(searchbar, 1.1)
```

```css
.searchbar {
  background-image: url("https://static.thenounproject.com/png/3134345-200.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.2vw auto;
  background-position: 1.7vw center;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1.5vw 0vw 1.5vw 4vw;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0vw 0.29282576866764276vw 1.4641288433382138vw rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.16);
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

#searchbar-1:hover {
  zoom: 1.1; /* Wrapping div border changes with zoom */
}

#searchbar-2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1); /* Wrapping div border does not change with scale */
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div><input placeholder="City" class="searchbar" id="searchbar-1" /></div>

<div><input placeholder="City" class="searchbar" id="searchbar-2" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `style.setProperty(string, string)`. The first parameter is the **CSS atttribute** and the second parameter is the **CSS value**. Both of them need to be `strings` in order to work.

```
const searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar-1")

const zoom = (element, value) => {
  element.style.setProperty('zoom', value);
}

zoom(searchbar, '1.1')
```

Comment: No I don't want to use the existing way of zooming (by setting its property). I want to create my own function for zooming of an element. If I do what you did, the zoom property will be different across browsers and Mozilla Firefox does not support it.

Comment: use ```transform: scale()``` cause it supported for most of the browsers and use custom variables to access it via javascript easily

Comment: @Grinnex. Well I already knew how to do that but sure.